# jQuery .each through POST nested array

Tags: jquery, multidimensional-array, nested, each

I have a POST that looks something like this:

```
Array
(
[students] => Array
    (
        [37] => Array
            (
                [name] => 37
                [registration_payment_date] => 
                [check_amount] => 120.00
            )

        [38] => Array
            (
                [name] => 38
                [registration_payment_date] => 9-11-2011
                [check_amount] => 117.00 

            )
     )
)
```

I want to loop through the key and value of the inner array in the .submit function to verify that if there is a check amount then there should be a payment date. If no payment date then I will add that name to an array then alert that list of names.
I'm having trouble with the jQuery.each function. I'm assuming there should be an outer .each and an inner .each. I have var form = this then-

```
var names = "";
jQuery(form.students).each(function(){
    //ANOTHER EACH HERE?? {
        //AN IF STATEMENT HERE {
            names.push( students['name'];
        }
    })
});
alert(names);
```

I'm close, I think, but not quite there. Can anyone fill in the blanks (or tell me I'm off track) please?

Answer (score 1):

You pretty much have it, when you use jQuery each, it gives you an index of the current item you are looping over. we use `i` in this case.

```
var names = "";
$(form.students).each(function(i,el){
    $(form.students[i].each, function() {
        //AN IF STATEMENT HERE {
            names.push( students[i]['name'];
        }
    })
});
alert(names);
```

Comment: I like the use of i, because I can see index, but I've replaced the push with alert(this.name); and get a blank alert box. Still close, thank you for your help!

Comment: try alert(students[i]['name'])

Comment: I put 'alert( 'hello' );' inside the second loop, without the 'if', but it doesn't get there. Do you have an idea as to why not? Should I be doing something with form.data? I'm not very comfortable with jQuery, so what's happening isn't clear in my head.

Answer (score 0):

```
var names=new Array();
$.each('form.students',function(){
    $.each(this,function() {
            names.push(this.name);
        });
    });
alert(names);
```

I removed if because i cant get what u want clearly so u can put yourself accordingly.
Is this what ur looking for.

Comment: I think this is just the thing. However if I replace the push with alert(this.name); I get 'undefined'. At least it's looping through, which I wasn't getting before. Thank you!

Comment: U can accept the answer by clicking on the tick if u feel it helped u.